# A word to describe evidence gained from hearsay and individual examples

Tags: single-word-requests

I know there is a word for this, but for the life of me I cannot recall it.  It's used to distinguish evidence from individual examples and stories vs. evidence based on large-scale data analysis.

Comment: Anecdotal or hearsay itself

Comment: Anecdotal! Yes, that is it.

Comment: Related (at least): [Is there a word or term to describe when someone focuses on a specific example?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222906/is-there-a-word-or-term-to-describe-when-someone-focuses-on-a-specific-example/223367#223367).